# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 431

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, jwt

I recently reworked my work's MEAN
web app to use socket.io and socket.io-client version 3.x from 2.x. We also use auth0-socketio-jwt for initial authentication.

In order to work with the new socket.io versions, I had to change the authentication method of auth0-socketio-jwt - instead of sending an authentication message in a two way trip, the token is now stored in the url "query" in a one way trip.

auth0-socketio-jwt authentication options: ( I am using the first option)

```
Append the jwt token using query string:

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000', {
  query: `token=${your_jwt}`
});

Append the jwt token using 'Authorization Header' (Bearer Token):

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000', {
  extraHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${your_jwt}` }
});
```

I have to do this instead of a header because our app is configured for websockets only.  Socket.io-client cannot send headers if the app uses websockets only.

Everything works fine in my dev environment, but when I get to our staging environment, I get this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://<website.com>/socket.io/?token=<token goes here>&EIO=4&transport=websocket' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 431
```

The entire URL with the header is quite long. A curl version of the entire request saved in notepad is 5.84 KB.

I don't get this issue locally, only in the staging environment. Other than the localhost:3000 adress being slightly shorter, I can't find any other difference between when app running locally or not.

I know node at one point limited http headers to be 8 KB or less, but the default is now 16 KB and we are on node 14. Does this not apply to websocket requests? Is there any way to set a max websocket request size?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the server you are attempting to connect to accept socket.io connections?  Or only accept webSocket connections?  I ask because you cannot connect a socket.io client to a webSocket server.

Comment: If the problem only happens when you are running it hosted, then you may need to configure something in the hosting provider to permit webSocket connections (often a proxy setting) and the 431 error would possibly indicate that type of problem.

Comment: If you look up the 431 http status, it says "Request Header Fields Too Large".  Perhaps your hosting provider has a limit on incoming headers.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes the server is set up with socket.io so it should work. we also have been using socket.io and socket.io client for a long time now, it is only with changing the authentication behavior that i'm seeing this issue, so it's not like websocket conns arent allowed. I can see the last one being possible, i'll look into it, Thanks.
 I was also told by someone else that a token of almost 5 KB is quite large.  I think I'm going to end up forking auth0-socketio-jwt and making it work with socket.io 3.x.x

Comment: FYI, you could work-around this by not sending the JWT with the initial http connection and just send it immediately after connection in a message.  The socket would have to be marked on the server as not-authenticated so no other messages were allowed until it was authenticated and disconnect automatically after a few seconds if auth didn't come.  It's not clear to me why switching versions of socket.io would have anything to do with this problem.  The header limit seems to be coming from your hosting solution, not from socket.io.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. I'm working around this by not upgrading -_-